# How to test if symmetric matrix is PSD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a matrix that is symmetric, is there a simple way to test if it is PSD?  Let us assume that GCT won't work.  To me, the simplest (yet probably most naive) test would be solve for the smallest eigenvalue using standard iterative methods.  But, I would like to avoid this for computational costs.  Is there any other way to easily and cheaply test such a matrix for PSD?

Comment: [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) is pretty good, but I suppose determinant computations tend to explode over $n$.  What's GCD?

Comment: sorry, that was meant to be GCT (Gershgorin's circle theorem).. fixed

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "cheaply," but if you're interested in complexity theory, Sylvester's Criterion, as mentioned above isn't that bad, running in $O(n^{4.75})$ time.

Comment: @StellaBiderman ah, good to know.  It must be that you can optimize the determinant computations

Comment: I should have been more specific with cheaply:  I was ideally hoping for an algorithm that would require at most $2n$ additional entries to be stored in memory.

Comment: Yup. There's a 1974 paper by Aho et al. that does det(M) in $O(n^{2.373})$ where $M$ is $n\times n$. Memory complexity is something I'm less familiar with, but I'll think about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do a Cholelesky decomposition using the standard cholesky algorithm. If it succeeds then it is PSD, if it breaks down along the way (e.g. dividing by zero, taking the square root of a negative number, what have you), then it is not.

Comment: Neat idea! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: this is interesting.. do you think it would be possible to carry out this test without explicitly storing the resulting lower triangular matrix?

Comment: @science404 I guess you wouldn't need to store it, but you would need to keep filling in the lower right blocks with the sequence of low-rank Schur complement updates. Saving memory when doing cholesky factorizations is going to depend a lot on whether the matrix is sparse or dense, what the sparsity structure is, etc. You might want to look into the work of Tim Davis, he wrote the code behind Matlab's sparse cholesky solver, and has a lot of good material online (videos, papers, etc) about this sort of thing.

Comment: To add, for sparse matrices the general take-away message is that with a good nodal ordering, the memory needed will be of order $O(\log(n) k^2)$, where the matrix is $n-by-n$, and $k$ is the number of degrees of freedom in the "separator front" that partitions the degrees of freedom into distinct pieces that only interact through that separator front.